When i reload the page on the browser some variables do not populate properly
In React, every time I reload the page, I receive correctly the JSON from the backend, then I put this array into a function to delete all the key that contain null values. If I console.log the variable, it is always empty. The strange thing is that if I modify something about some file and save them, when I switch again into the browser without reloading the page, it populate properly all the variables, this issue come up only when I reload the page.
This is a sample of the JSON that I receive from the backend:
    [
    {date:01/01/2024, categorieEntrate: lavoro, categorieUscite: spesa, account: banca},
    {date:01/02/2024, categorieEntrate: lavoro, categorieUscite: spesa, account: banca},
    {date:01/03/2024, categorieEntrate: lavoro, categorieUscite: spesa, account: banca},
    {date:01/05/2024, categorieEntrate: null, categorieUscite: spesa, account: banca},
    {date:01/07/2024, categorieEntrate: null, categorieUscite: spesa, account: null},
    {date:01/10/2024, categorieEntrate: null, categorieUscite: spesa, account: null},
    {date:01/12/2024, categorieEntrate: null, categorieUscite: spesa, account: null},
    ]


Below is the code:
    const [mesePerMese, setMesePerMese] = useState([]);
    const [annoPerAnno, setAnnoPerAnno] = useState([]);
    const [categorie, setCategorie] = useState([]);       

 useEffect(() => {

        fetch("http://localhost:3000/impostazioni")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                let a = data["data"];
                console.log("ciao")
                console.log(a);

                let estratto = estraiCategorieEntrateUscite(a);
                setCategorie(estratto);
                console.log(categorie) //when I console.log here the array is empty
            });


        fetch("http://localhost:3000/transazioni")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                let dati = data["data"];
                const formattato = ISOitaliano(dati);
                const ordinato = ordinaDate(formattato);

                let b = new Statistiche(categorie[0], categorie[1]);

                ordinato.map(rigo => {
                    b.aggiungiTransazione(rigo);
                })
                setMesePerMese(b.ottieniMesePerMese());
                setAnnoPerAnno(b.ottieniAnnoPerAnno());
                console.log("anno per anno")
                console.log(annoPerAnno);
                console.log("mese per mese");
                console.log(mesePerMese);


            });


    }, [])



export function estraiCategorieEntrateUscite(array) {

    let categorieEntrate = [], categorieUscite = [];
    
    array.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item["categorieEntrate"] !== null && item["categorieEntrate"] !== undefined) {
            categorieEntrate.push(item["categorieEntrate"]);
        }
        if (item["categorieUscite"] !== null && item["categorieUscite"] !== undefined) {
            categorieUscite.push(item["categorieUscite"]);
        }
    });

console.log(categorieEntrate); //i console.log here and the array is fine
console.log(categorieUscite); //i console.log here and the array is fine



    return [categorieEntrate, categorieUscite];
}


//when I console.log here the array is empty - that's normal, setCategorie does not change categorie until the next render.

@James Understood, in this case how can I adjust my code to fill properly the variable and render the components when i refresh the page?

Your second fetch is using categorie[0] and categorie[1] which only exist after a rerender.  You can use estratto instead, but only if the first fetch is complete.
You could chain the fetches using .then, or you could use Promise.all to wait until both are complete before using the data in a combined .then handler.  Here is an example of Promise.all.


useEffect(() => {
  // combine the two fetch operations into one promise
  Promise.all([
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/impostazioni").then(res => res.json().data),
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/transazioni").then(res => res.json().data)
  ]).then(([impos, trans]) => {
    // in this function we get the data from both fetch operations once they are both complete
    let estratto = estraiCategorieEntrateUscite(impos);
    setCategorie(estratto);
  
    const formattato = ISOitaliano(trans);
    const ordinato = ordinaDate(formattato);
    
    // use estratto for this part because setCategorie hasn't updated categorie yet
    let b = new Statistiche(estratto[0], estratto[1]);

    ordinato.map(rigo => {
        b.aggiungiTransazione(rigo);
    })
    setMesePerMese(b.ottieniMesePerMese());
    setAnnoPerAnno(b.ottieniAnnoPerAnno());
    console.log("anno per anno")
    console.log(annoPerAnno);
    console.log("mese per mese");
    console.log(mesePerMese);
  })
});



